# Индекс находился вне границ массива, что не так

Tags: c#, массивы

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] massive = new int[10] { 5, -2, 3, -5, 11, 2, 1, -10, 13, 8 };
    int[] NewMassive = new int[massive.Length];
    int counter = 0;
    Console.Write("Введённый массив: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < massive.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(massive[i] + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < massive.Length; i++)
    {
        if (massive[i] > 0 && counter!=5)
        {
            NewMassive[massive.Length] = massive[i];
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine($"\nМассив с положительными числами:{NewMassive}");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Ошибку выводит на строчке `NewMassive[massive.Length] = massive[i];`

**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."**

Comment: Если `massive.Length` равен 10, то индексы массива в диапазоне `0-9`, а вы обращаетесь к 10 индексу, которого нет

Comment: Пытаюсь угадать, что вам нужно: `NewMassive[counter] = massive[i];`

Comment: спасибо, решено